# How to convert 'x' minute format to 'xx' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm making a VB.NET software, and want to show minute format as XX minute, e.g: "05 minute left" and not like this: "5 minute left." My code now like this:

```vb
min = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") + NumericUpDown2.Value
```

I've tried with big "MM" letters but it's just another time format.

Is that a countdown application, and when I'm try to check the time failed.

```vb
If Date.Time.Minutes = min Than
   Alarm.show
End If
```

Comment: What type of variable is `min`? Are you performing addition or concatenation? If addition: You cannot format the number before you display it. `DateTime.Now.ToString("mm")` will be converted _back_ into an integer (integers have no format) before being added with `NumericUpDown2.Value`.

Comment: Set Option Strict On.  No matter what type `min` is, the rest of the code is gluing a number to a string.

Comment: min is string and if i display text to any label and add NumericUpDown2.Value i get ineffectual numbers. e.g min = 10 and NumericUpDown2.Value = 15 i get this: 1015 :/

Comment: You are appending strings here! To get the integer values added, you should be using some parsing mechanism such as `Integer.Parse` here. But first of all, set option strict on and the rest will become visible.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this code has not been tested it should give you some ideas of how to proceed. As far as the formatting is concerned - right pew, wrong church. Number.ToString("00")

```
Private AlarmTime As DateTime
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AlarmTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(NumericUpDown1.Value)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim TimeLeft As TimeSpan = AlarmTime - DateTime.Now
    Dim MinutesLeft As Integer = TimeLeft.Minutes
    Label1.Text = MinutesLeft.ToString("00")
    If AlarmTime >= DateTime.Now Then
        Alarm.Show()
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is like this:

```
DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00")
```